# Assign values to an associated array in a loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a difficult time creating an associated array and assigning a value to the key. I have two arrays (tech_pay and tech_scans) and I am doing a simple calculation using their values and I want to create a new array called tech_per_scan but I keep getting an array with the key automatically created starting at 0.

```
    $tech_per_scan = array();
    foreach($tech_pay as $key=>$value)
    {  
        $pay_per_scan = $tech_pay[$key]['tot_pay']/$tech_scans[$key]['scans'];//calculate the payment per scan 
        $tech_per_scan[] = array('id'=>$key,'pay_per_scan'=>$pay_per_scan); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `$tech_per_scan[] = array('id'=>$key,'pay_per_scan'=>$pay_per_scan);` will add an element to you array and it will start with 0 as its index, because you did not specify its key. Similar to [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

It should be `$tech_per_scan[$id]`

Comment: Thank you. I have got it now. Your explanations helped perfectly!

Comment: One last question: How do you close a question on this site?

Comment: You need to accept an answer by clicking on the "v" thing or delet ethe question

Answer (score 1):

```
$tech_per_scan[$id] = $pay_per_scan;
```

Comment: No, that does not work. If I print_r it I don't get the id:Array ( [] => 0 )

Answer (score 0):

you should set value for new array like this :

```
$tech_per_scan[$key] = $pay_per_scan ;
```

Full code is :

```
    $tech_per_scan = array();
    foreach($tech_pay as $key=>$value)
    {  
        $pay_per_scan = $tech_pay[$key]['tot_pay']/$tech_scans[$key]['scans'];//calculate the payment per scan 
        $tech_per_scan[$key] = $pay_per_scan ; 
    }
```